# Goodness of fit tests in SciPy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I'm new to Python and coming from the R world. I'm trying to fit distributions to sample data using SciPy and having good success. I can make `distribution.fit(data)` return sane results. What I've been unable to do is create the goodness of fit statistics which I'm used to with the `fitdistrplus` package in R. Is there a common method for comparing "best fit" from a number of different distributions with SciPy?

I'm looking for something like the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test or Cramer-von Mises or
Anderson-darling tests

Comment: For which distributions to you need the gof tests? With estimated parameters the distribution of the test statistic is different from the one with fully specified distributions. statsmodels, see John D Cooks' answer, has more in the sandbox and should be available by the end of summer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's also [statmodels goodness of fit tests](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/stats.html#goodness-of-fit-tests-and-measures).

Answer (score 17):

See the scipy.stats library: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

It contains K-S and Anderson-Darling, although apparently not Cramer-von Mises.

Comment: many thanks! I wish I could accept both your answer and John's.

Comment: Cramer-von Mises test is available with scipy.stats: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statistical-tests