# Multivariate normality test in Python

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

Is there a multivariate normality test available in any of packages in Python?

I have heard of some scipy functions but are they applicable to multivariate data? I have a dataset with 30000 datapoints each point with 1024 variables. I want to check if these variables have multivariate normal distribution. How do I do this in Python.

Comment: Any update on assessing multivariate normality in python? Like the MVN package in R. Any equivalent in python?

Comment: I havent needed to do multivariate normality test for a long time now, I dont think they have any libraries catering to it yet.

Comment: Yes, see here an MVN test in Python: https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.multivariate_normality.html

Answer (score 1):

Using scipy you can create samples of random variable from multivariate normal distribution. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html).

If you already have a sample that was generated using multivariate normal distribution, but you don't know its parameters, you can use [maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) to estimate them ([see this example](https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2016/09/16/fitting-multivariate-normal-distributions/)).

If you have a sample and you want to test if it was generated using multivariate normal distribution, you can use [goodness of fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268632/goodness-of-fit-tests-in-scipy) for relevant scipy methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I went through the goodness of fit tests in scipy stats models and they all seem to require their input parameter x i.e the data matrix to be 1-d array. If I am not wrong in my understanding, then that means these scipy tests are for univariate data, right ?

Comment: @chilvandu yes it seems to be the case. One option is to calculate the chi-square test statistics yourself and then look for the p-value, as in this example: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/259

Comment: Any update on assessing multivariate normality in python? Like the MVN package in R? Any equivalent in python?

Comment: @seralouk MVN test in Python: https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.multivariate_normality.html